# Monitor Application resources utilization

Tags: ubuntu, system, monitoring

I am working on a application where I need to monitor a process. I need to check which files that process is accessing/reading/writing and socket connect with external IP address, memory utilization etc. I am working on ubuntu.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Which language are u using?

Comment: what's your QUESTION ?

Comment: I am just looking for a Tool for this. My application is in C/Python mix.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read files of your process under /proc/$YOUR_PID/